# Add text to wordpress admin 'Add Post' edit

Tags: custom-post-types, admin

I'd like to add some descriptive text underneath the page title on both the list and edit post screens for the default post and also custom post types - e.g. "Below is a list of your recent blog posts."

What's the best way to do this?

I need to make add a list of instructions as in:

xxxx
2. xxxxx
3. xxxx

I'm guessing I'll need to add html for this?

And ideally I can change the font and make it bold.

Thanks!

This is the text I need:

> "To add a video, you need to make sure that the video is first uploaded to Youtube or Vimeo or Google Videos.

1. In the 'Video Embed Code', enter the video embed code (`http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780`)
   The thumbnail will Automatically be added
2. Enter title and text in the main panel below
3. Choose which continent and category that is most fitting for your video
4. Press "Publish"

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard, you can use the `all_admin_notices`-hook, which appears beneath the `Post Updated/Saved`, etc. messages box.

Wrapped up in a plugin:

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/** Plugin Name: (#64933) »kaiser« Add post/page note */

function wpse64933_add_posttype_note()
{
    global $post, $pagenow;

    // Abort in certain conditions, based on the global $pagenow
    if ( ! in_array(
         $pagenow
        ,array(
             'post-new.php'
            ,'post.php'
         )
    ) )
        return;

    // Abort in certain conditions, based on the global $post
    if ( ! in_array(
         $post->post_type
        ,array(
             'post'
            ,'page'
         )
    ) )
        return;

    // You can use the global $post here
    echo '<p>HELLO WORLD!</p>';
}
add_action( 'all_admin_notices', 'wpse64933_add_posttype_note' );
```

Comment: +1 for `Abort in certain conditions`

Comment: `add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse64933_add_posttype_note' );` also possible and displayed underneath a page title when given `notice notice-info` like CSS classes.
see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/

Comment: @AndréKelling Feel free to file an edit.